# Break out line items in one cell and separate

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have data that has multiple entries in one cell and I needed the individual entries broken on into multiple cells.

For example:

in Cell A1 I have this data:

```
Corporate
Dr. 1392.9999 Accounts Receivable Reconciled
 Cr. 1092.5921 Other Revenues

Back Office
Dr. 9821.0000 Accounts Payable
 Cr. 4322.9820 Redemptions Payable

Note: These accounts are related to the payments received and sold.
```

I needed all of the Dr. and Cr. line items separated into separate cells.

For example, in Cell A2 I need

```
Dr. 1392.9999 Accounts Receivable Reconciled
```

And cell A3 to be

```
Cr. 1092.5921 Other Revenues
```

And cell A4 to be

```
Dr. 9821.0000 Accounts Payable
```

And Cell A5 to be

```
Cr. 4322.9820 Redemptions Payable
```

I tried using text to columns and using line breaks but it breaks out all of the data in the cell but I just need the Dr. and Cr. line items.

Thanks

Comment: On the third screen of the text to columns wizard, there is an option to skip any or all result columns.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the 2 versions bellow

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExtractDrCrV1()
    Dim txt As String, arr As Variant, drcr As Variant, itm As Variant, r As Long

    txt = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value2
    arr = Split(txt, Chr(10))
    ReDim drcr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
    For Each itm In arr
        If InStr(1, itm, "Dr.") > 0 Or InStr(1, itm, "Cr.") > 0 Then
            r = r + 1
            drcr(r, 1) = Trim$(itm)
        End If
    Next
    Sheet1.Range("A2:A" & r + 1) = drcr
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub ExtractDrCrV2()

    Const R1 = "A1"
    Const R2 = "A2"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheet1
        .Range(R1).TextToColumns Destination:=.Range(R2), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                 Other:=True, OtherChar:=Chr(10)
        .UsedRange.Rows(2).Copy
        .Range(R2).Offset(1).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True: .Range(R1).Select
        With .UsedRange.Columns(1)
         .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>*Dr.*", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<>*Cr.*"
          Sheet1.UsedRange.Offset(1).EntireRow.Delete
         .AutoFilter
        End With
        .UsedRange.Offset(1).Columns(1).Replace " Cr.", "Cr."
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```